# Listbox subscript out of range excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, split, listbox

I'm trying to get the split the item in the listbox such that i only display up to the first line break, however it appears that the subscript is out of range, and i couldn't pinpoint the error.

```
Private Sub DisplayTasksInListView()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim taskList As Variant
    Dim taskItem As Variant

    With ListBoxTask
      ListBoxTask.Clear
      taskList = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B5")
      For Each taskItem In taskList
        ListBoxTask.AddItem Split(taskItem, Chr(10))(0)
      Next taskItem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you close the sub: `End Sub`

Comment: hi i did close the sub in the original code, just that i forgot to include in this post

Comment: You are playing very lose with data types. `taskitem` is a range which you assign to a variant. Then you intend to get that range's default property, the `Value` and split it. Try specifying the `Value` property, so that Excel can know you don't mean to split the range object. However, the `Value` property could be a string as required by the Split function. And, of course, the list box requires a string as well, not a variant. I suspect that the error will have disappeared once you add a little precision to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to @Variatus advice - if you create your variables with the correct data types, your code basically is OK. `taskList` and `taskItem` should be of type `Range`. For a cell, you can then explicitly refer to the `Value` property for that `Range` and pass that to `Split`.

I've also added a way to get the `ListBox` by name, rather than refer to it directly. This will make it easier to make your code modular if you need to.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillListBox()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngTaskList As Range
    Dim rngTaskItem As Range
    Dim lstTasks As MSForms.ListBox

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- change for your sheet
    Set rngTaskList = ws.Range("B1:B5") '<-- change for your range
    Set lstTasks = ws.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value '<-- change for your listbox name

    With lstTasks
        .Clear
        For Each rngTaskItem In rngTaskList
            .AddItem Split(rngTaskItem.Value, vbLf)(0)
        Next rngTaskItem
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]